# Prometheus node_exporter in docker: Host networking vs hostnames

Tags: docker, docker-compose, prometheus, prometheus-node-exporter

To monitor a small home server, I run prometheus and node_exporter (and grafana, and several more things) on docker (similar to https://github.com/stefanprodan/dockprom). I run prometheus on a bridged docker network. For node_exporter, I have two options, which affect the `node_network_transmit_bytes_total` metric.

- Using the same bridged docker network as prometheus

  - Pro: nodeexporter can be addressed directly by name, thanks to docker's internal DNS
  - Con: The `node_network_transmit_bytes_total` metric only has docker's virtual internal NIC, not the physical NIC of the box being monitored. This is depsite bind-mounting `/proc` from the host into `/host/proc` in the container (specifically my physical interface is `eno0`, visible in `/proc/net/dev` on the host):

    ```
    $ docker exec -it nodeexporter2 cat /host/proc/net/dev | awk '{print $1}'
    Inter-|
    face
    eth0:
    lo:
    ```
- Using host-mode networking for nodeexporter

  - Pro: All NICs, including the physical host NIC, are visible
  - Con: There does not appear to be a clean way for prometheus to address nodeexporter:

    - `localhost` means prometheus itself
    - Hostname of host seems inaccessible? Running `docker exec -it prometheus wget -O - http://actual-hostname:9100/metrics` works (and uses my host's LAN IP, 192.168.x.x), but configuring `actual-hostname:9100` as a prometheus target gives an error (`Get "http://actual-hostname:9100/metrics": dial tcp 127.0.1.1:9100: connect: connection refused`). I'm not sure why they're resolving differently.
    - What I ended up doing is emulating the `host.docker.internal` feature available for docker-on-windows and docker-on-mac, by adding this to my `docker-compose.yml`:

      ```yaml
      extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:172.18.0.1"
      ```

      That's very brittle, however: That 172.18 was just recently 172.19; I believe it changed on reboot or docker version upgrade. I'd love to do be able to set the `extra_hosts` to a result of running some script on the host to determine the correct network name, but that wouldn't automatically be re-run on boot.

Any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Late edit**: Thanks to [thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858934/thomas), turns out there's a magic host `host-gateway` that does this, so `extra_hosts: ["host.docker.internal:host-gateway"]` should do the trick.  undocumented, but apparently it's implemented [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/commit/9895d90167354f11c34787d9be850c21b087f5d9). and already live in docker 20.10.6 (and likely earlier).

---

I ended up solving this by manually configuring the network:

```yaml
networks:
  monitor-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.23.0.0/16
          ip_range: 172.23.5.0/24
          gateway: 172.23.5.254

# ...

services:
  nodeexporter:
    network_mode: host
    # ...
  prometheus:
    networks:
      - monitor-net
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal: 172.23.5.254"
```

Then prometheus has the target of `host.docker.internal` for node_exporter, and the address should be stable.

Comment: In newer docker versions you can use
`extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`
and don't have to configure the network manually.

Comment: Huh, cool! It's undocumented, but apparently it's implemented [here](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/commit/9895d90167354f11c34787d9be850c21b087f5d9) and already live in docker 20.10.6 (and likely earlier).